# In which case does FCM membership converge to 1/K?

Tags: clustering, fuzzy, fuzzy-c-means-clustering

I have tested the [fuzzy C-means (FCM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_Analysis#Fuzzy_c-means_clustering) algorithm using the R function `fanny` from the `cluster` package and I have wrote my own FCM algorithm to have more control on the distance function. The problem is that my final membership function converges many times to the 1/K, I mean almost all the values in the membership matrix are near to 1/K.
I am wondering what are the conditions that influence the final result. I am using  fuzzy parameter m=2.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that mbq! Now I can be *sure* I'm not qualified to answer the question!